# Updation needs in both the client and server database(MYSQL,ASP.NET,C#.NET)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

i have a site for room reservation, the same room reservation facility is available in local counter system also , at some situation if the local counter staff made the reservation through site then the liability amount must be affect in both the server and client database how to do this , I had use ASP.NET,C#.NET,MYSQL

Comment: i dont think Updation is a word

Comment: also i have no idea what you are asking

Comment: the room reservation facility in site is available to both the public and our client's counter staff. if the public made the reservation they are paid the reservation fees by D.D , if the counter staff made the reservation for public they get the money directly from public this amount liability must reflect in the counter staff liability register that means (it needs to add this amount to local system database)

Comment: you need to make a website!

Comment: I already have the website with the room reservation facility

Answer (score 0):

You will need a database on your local server (where the site is hosted) and then u can send the information of the reservation to the hotel and store for you